# Button's DialogResult not being (re-)set?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In my Windows Forms application, I have a child form which is launched as a modal by my main form. The child form acts as a wizard to perform a long-running task, and contains a "cancel" button. In the designer, I have this "cancel" button's `DialogResult` property set to `DialogResult.Cancel`. However, if the user resists pressing the "cancel" button until the long operation is completed, the text of the "cancel" button changes to "close". I would like the button's `DialogResult` to be `DialogResult.None` if this happens.

Unfortunately, the setting does not seem to persist. To maintain a responsive UI, the long-running task runs in a separate `Task`, and then the UI updating after the task has finished is done in a `ContinueWith` block afterward, which in turn uses `Invoke` to do the UI work. It looks something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    MyStaticClass.DoLotsOfWork(a, b, myCancellationToken);
    return MyStaticClass.TellMeAboutIt(a, c, myCancellationToken);
}, myCancellationToken)
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    switch(task.Status)
    {
    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            cancelButton.Text = "Close";
            cancelButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            // other UI-related stuff.
        }
    // Other cases here...
    }
});
```

When I run the code, the text gets set to "Close", no problem. The `DialogResult` *seems* to change: if I walk through using the debugger, the debugger tells me the value has been changed. However, when the window is closed (using the cancel/close button), the `DialogResult` returned by `myWindow.ShowDialog()` is *always* `DialogResult.Cancel`.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Can a person not set the `DialogResult` of a button programmatically on-the-fly?

Comment: One thing you could do is perhaps remove both `DialogResult`s and just handle it in the `Button_Click` event.  Then just set `DialogResult` depending on the `Button.Text` property.

Comment: I wrote a quick test app and I can't reproduce that problem.  I bet something else is setting the DialogResult.  How is the child form actually getting closed?

Comment: How are you closing the modal form?

Comment: Using `this.Close()`, in the event handler `cancelButton_Click`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more than one reason why the DialogResult would be set to Cancel.  You could for example make the mistake of calling Close() in the button's Click event handler.  That closes the window but since DialogResult was never assigned, Winforms must assume Cancel.  Hiding the window is another way to trigger this, a window can't stay modal when you make it invisible.  Necessarily so, all other windows are disabled and the last remaining one was hidden, the user can never get back to the program again.

The sane way to deal with dialog state is to only ever set the DialogResult property.  As soon as you change it from None to something else, Winforms will close the dialog and the dialog result is unambiguous.  So consider removing the Click event handler and changing the code to:

```
case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        cancelButton.Text = "Close";
        cancelButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "You could for example make the mistake of calling Close() in the button's Click event handler. That closes the window but since DialogResult was never assigned, Winforms must assume Cancel" ? Does `Close()` not cause the `DialogResult` of the clicked button to be returned?

Comment: Is there a good reason for me to have to guess what the Click event handler looks like?  But I'll put a buck on it being wrong.  If you close the window but don't say why you closed it, Winforms has no better guess than Cancel.  Don't call Close(), set the DialogResult property.

Comment: this.Close() does not change the DialogResult.

Comment: Aaaahh, I feel like an idiot now. Just finished (re-)reading the MSDN docs on DialogResult. Yes Hans, I do call Close() explicitly. I was unaware that a button with its DialogResult property set would automatically close the window! Thanks.

Comment: this is exactly where I was going. well said Hans.